# SignIn link generation on Cognito Signup

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, serverless

In our application, The admin will sign the user up and an email will be sent to the user through our email service. The email should have a "link" that will have the username" in it and the password (maybe?). Password should otherwise be in the email. When the user clicks on the link, The username field in the form should automatically fill in the username (we can be used a query parameter for that?) but the link should probably be encrypted when it is sent in the email.

Any ideas on how can think the link to be sent in the email be generated?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're really trying to achieve here. I think what you're referring to is a 'magic link' (https://auth0.com/docs/connections/passwordless/guides/email-magic-link).

A magic link, when clicked, signs a user into your application. The way to implement this is *not* by sending a username/password encoded in a link, but rather by sending an OTP (one time passcode) in the link.

The link you send would contain the path to an applications endpoint (lets say example.com/magiclink/ZXCBN123). You would need an application client that takes the OTP and performs a cognito sign-in.

I've implemented this myself and its not very well supported by Cognito. When you send the email, you create the OTP and persist it in some database. When the client sends you the OTP you look it up and validate it. You have to use the custom challenge/response cognito triggers to verify that the code is correct, and return tokens if it is.